# Initialize from within instance method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

In my Rails application. I have a module in which I am overriding `.eql?` method like below

```
# lib/item_util.rb

module ItemUtil
  def eql?(item, field: "cost", op: "==")
    item.send(field).present? &&
      item.send(field).send(op, self.send(field))
  end
end
```

Which is included in `Item` model

```
# app/models/item.rb

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  include ItemUtil
end
```

In my controller I want to check various conditions based on the attribute values. Ex:

```
@item1 = Item.find(:id)
@item2 = Item.find(:id)

@item1.eql?(@item2, field: "discount", op: ">") # @item2.discount > @item1.discount
@item2.eql?(@item1, op: "<=") # @item1.cost <= @item2.cost

# ...
```

All this is working fine and I want to write `ItemUtil` module in a neater way like below:

```
  module ItemUtil
    attr_accessor :item, :field

    def initialize(item, field: "cost")
      @item = item
      @field = field
    end

    def eql?(item, field: "cost", op: "==")
      new_item.present? && new_item.send(op, current_item)
    end

    def new_item
      @item.send(@field)
    end

    def current_item
      self.send(@field)
    end
  end
```

This returns `TypeError (nil is not a symbol nor a string)` for `@field` inside `new_item` method, as `initialize` wasn't invoked anywhere

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from lib/item_util.rb:12:in `eql?'
        1: from lib/item_util.rb:17:in `new_item'
TypeError (nil is not a symbol nor a string)
```

but I dont want to change the way I call `.eql?` on object i.e., I'd like to keep these lines intact

```
@item1.eql?(@item2, field: "discount", op: ">") # @item2.discount > @item1.discount
@item2.eql?(@item1, op: "<=") # @item1.cost <= @item2.cost
```

- How do I get the `new_item` and `current_item` return the desired output?
- How to invoke `initialize` method within `.eql?` method?
- Is there an alternate approach for this?
- Is there a way to access parameters in modules similar to `before_action`(in controllers)?

Comment: Note that equality is expected to be _symmetric_, i.e. `a.eql?(b)` usually implies `b.eql?(a)`. This is no longer true the way you implemented `eql?`.

Comment: I have decided to rename it as `.compare?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an instance of a module. (You can instantiate an instance of a *class*, but not a *module*.)

In fact, what you are actually doing here is **overriding the definition of `Item#initialize`**!!

Sticking with your general design pattern, what I would suggest is to abstract this logic into a **new class** - like, say, `ItemComparator`:

```
class ItemComparator
  attr_reader :item, :other

  def initialize(item, other)
    @item = item
    @other = other
  end

  def eql?(field:, op:)
    item_field = item.send(field)
    other_field = other.send(:field)

    other_field.present? && item_field.send(op, other_field)
  end
end

module ItemUtil
  def eql?(other, field: "cost", op: "==")
    ItemComparator.new(self, other).eql?(field: field, op: op)
  end
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  include ItemUtil
end
```

Comment: However, there are some aspects of this design that are *dubious*.... For instance, why is this a desired design?? `@item1.eql?(@item2, field: "discount", op: ">")` -- You want to check if two items are equal, judging by whether **one field** is actually **greater** than the other?! That's super misleading.

Comment: At a bare minimum, perhaps this method should be called something like `compare?` instead of `eql?`!!

Comment: I wanted to perform `<=>` operation within the method. After your suggestion `compare?` makes more sense. Thanks for the solution, its very helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to instantiate even if I wrapped my module code inside `class << self ... end` block within module?

Comment: @ManjunathP You can not instantiate an instance of a module. This is the fundamental difference between a class and a module.